# Como adicionar classe ao primeiro <img src=""> de um conjunto

Tags: jquery

Galera , tenho um conjunto de `<img src=“”>`. Preciso, assim que a página for carregada, adicionar uma classe ao primeiro desse conjunto com `Jquery`, mas lembrando que eles possuem um parente, o `href`.

```
    ...
<a href="#">
    <img src=“” classe="SOMENTE AQUI">
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src=“”>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src=“”>
</a>
    ....
```

Answer (score 4):

Pode ser feito desta forma:

```
$("a img").first().addClass('classe');
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela ajuda! Muito útil sua resposta.

Comment: @Lollipop de nada

Answer (score 3):

Caso já tenha selecionado vários elementos, utilize [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/), como no exemplo:

```
$imgs = $('img');

$imgs.first().addClasse('classe');
```

Caso deseje seleciona-lo apenas para isso, passe como parâmetro no seletor, como no exemplo:

```
$('img:first').addClass('classe');
```

Dessa última forma, você "economiza tempo" selecionando apenas o elemento que deseja.

**Obs.:** Caso queira selecionar apenas elementos que contenham o atributo `src` adicione `[src]` ao seletor, assim:

```
$('img[src]:first')
```

Assim estará dizendo que é obrigatório o atributo `src` e só selecionará o primeiro que tiver o atributo, por exemplo:

```js
$('img[src]:first').addClass('borda');
```

```css
img{
   border: 5px solid #FFF;
  display:block;
}
.borda{
   border-color:#87C9F8;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img style="background:#999; width:200px; height:60px;">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x60">
<img style="background:#999; width:200px; height:60px;">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x60">
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela ajuda! Isso é válido!

Answer (score 3):

Não é preciso jQuery para fazer isso nos browsers modernos.
Tenho de colocar uma alternativa com JavaScript nativo já que ninguém colocou...

```
document.querySelector('a img').classList.add('novaClasse');
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/ffnyyu92/**

Comment: É um caso para: [too much jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) ;)

Comment: @Zuul haha esse link é muito bom! Os "Related" ao lado são a não perder tb...

Comment: Boa, mas não necessariamente.

Answer (score 0):

Está foi uma solução perfeita, pois facilita quando é colocada uma div de referência:

```
$('#referencia img:first').addClass('classe');
```

Comment: Não adicione uma nova resposta com o mesmo conteúdo, apenas marque a que te atendeu como certa. ;)

Comment: Não deveria ser  `$('a:first img').addClass('classe');` pois estará pegando a imagem que está no primeiro `<a>`? Ou não é isso que você quer?

Comment: @KaduAmaral provavelmente ele já tinha a resposta quando fez a pergunta e apenas queria uma forma de compartilhar, mas as outras respostas vieram antes de ele publicar a dele, hehe